# C++ struct with char arrays initialize to zero in unusual way

Tags: c++, initialization, aggregate-initialization

Came across a non-common bit of c++ initialization code that seems to work fine with the following...

```
struct sfoobar { char bar[10]; char foo[10]; };
...
sfoobar x { 0 };
```

Is this an acceptable method for initializing these char arrays to zero?

Comment: *non-common* it is actually quite common.

Comment: Yes, that is an acceptable way to do it.

Comment: `sfoobar x { };` would be a preferred pattern, because it still works even if `0` is not a correct initializer for the first member. Compare with `struct qux { std::string bar; char foo[10]; };`  , then `qux x{0};` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M Could you please elaborate why `qux x{0};` causes UB? Why wouldn't this simply generate a compile error instead? (If `std::string` doesn't support such initialization.)

Comment: @303 `std::string` has a constructor taking `char const *` (UB if null pointer passed) and `0` can be implicitly converted to null pointer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is valid in C++. As the effect `sfoobar x { 0 };` would initialize all the elements of `x.bar` and `x.foo` to `0`.

According to the rule of [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), the braces for nested initializer lists could be omitted,

> the braces around the nested initializer lists may be elided (omitted), in which case as many initializer clauses as necessary are used to initialize every member or element of the corresponding subaggregate, and the subsequent initializer clauses are used to initialize the following members of the object.

then `sfoobar x { 0 };` means initializing the 1st element of `x.bar` to `0`, and

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members `and bases (since C++17)` or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members `and bases (since C++17)` are initialized `by their default initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)` by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates).

So all the remaining elements, including the 2nd to 10th elements of `x.bar` and all the elements of `x.foo` would be value-initialized to `0` too.

Comment: question, is `value initialization` and `zero initialization` the same for char arrays?

Comment: @codekaizer Yes, for non-class types [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) leads to [zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization). For this case, the flow would be *aggregate initialization* on `char` array then *value initialization* on elements (i.e. `char`s) then *zero initialization* on elements (i.e. `char`s).

Comment: So if I write `sfoobar x { 1 };` instead, then the first element of `x.bar` is initialized to one, and all other elements of `x.bar` and all elements of `x.foo` are initialized to zero? And if I just write `sfoobar x`, then the values of the elements of `x.bar` and `x.foo` are undetermined?

Comment: @M.Winter Yes, exactly.